# How to add manufacturer on module ves-Brand?

Tags: magento2, module, manufacturer

can someone please show me how i can add manufacturer ? ; I have module Ves-Brand and i use magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the manufacturer attribute and add the options under manage labels.

Then you need to assign that attribute to your working attribute sets and select the manufacturer for each products.